# The network path cannot be found SSIS File System Task

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012

I am trying to upload a File onto the Sharepoint using a File System Task. When I run the package manually, it succeeds.

However, after I deploy it and run via SQL Agent Job I get the following error:

```
"The network path was not found"
```

Can you please help?

Comment: Permissions? Relative path?

Comment: Have you tried a proxy account ?

Comment: SQL Agent Job is likely running under a different account. Find out the account it is using and check permissions.

Answer (score 1):

When you run it locally you are using your windows credentials to authenticate through to the sharepoint site.  A sql job will not use your windows credentials. You can setup a proxy account, but make sure it has permissions to the sharepoint site as well.